# Scroll page when using HTML5 drag and drop api

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using [HTML5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) to rearrange items in a list horizontal list. This list is a timeline and overflows off screen to the left and right.

Is there a plugin or technique that would enable left or right scrolling on the timeline when dragging an object?

Answer (score 1):

implemenation of drag and scroll divs:

http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/scrollpane.html

plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Dragscrollable